# Remove row only if all values are 0 or NA

Tags: r

If I have a row which consists of say:

```
0   NA  0   NA  0   NA  NA
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   NA  1   0   0   0   0
```

I want to get rid of only the first row and not the second or third ones, which have at least one non-zero character. How would I do this?

I've checked for subsetting with the `is.na` function, but that removes any row which has a `NA` value. I also can't change the dataset itself, because 0 sometimes means something.

Comment: What would you replace it with?

Comment: What do you mean by 'replace'?

Comment: You mean "get rid of the only the first row", not column?

Comment: The detailed description suggests that you want to remove `column`. There is confusion it seems your heading is not matching with description.

Comment: My mistake there, it should have been row

Comment: Okay fine. I was confused with mismatch in heading and detailed. Hence added solution for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid `apply(m,1,...)` as it will be slow on any reasonably large data. `rowSums` is usually good for these kind of tasks:

```
m[rowSums(m != 0, na.rm=TRUE) > 0,]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#[1,]  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
#[2,]  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0
```

Where `m` was:

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text="0   NA  0   NA  0   NA  NA
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   NA  1   0   0   0   0"))
```

Comment: What is `m` in `rowSums`?

Answer (score 1):

The below does the job:

```
is_valid <- function(my_row){
    any(my_row!=0, na.rm = TRUE)
}

valid_df <- df[which(apply(df, 1, FUN = is_valid)),]

valid_df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
2  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
3  0 NA  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: what does the 1 mean in the second parameter for apply?

Comment: It means that you are applying the function to the rows of a dataframe: use 1 for rows and 2 for columns.

Answer (score 1):

The below applies a function to each row, that basically just returns true if each element is either a 0 or NA, then checks to see whether or not they were all one of those. The second argument `1` simply means *apply to rows*. A `2` would indicate *apply to columns*.

```
goodRows <- apply(df, 1, function(x){sum(x %in% c(0,NA)) != length(x)})

df <- df[goodRows,]
```

The `goodRows` bit can just be taken out and placed straight in the df row argument if you want a one line solution :)

```
df <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x){sum(x %in% c(0,NA)) != length(x)}),]
```

The advantage of this solution, is because we don't use `na.rm` in any of the functions, you can change the vector `c(0,NA)` to whatever you want. Later you might want to remove `-1`s as well, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(a = c(0, NA, 0, 4, NA, 0), b = c(1, NA, 0, 4, NA, 0), c = c(1, 0, 1, NA, NA, 0))

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1
2    NA    NA     0
3     0     0     1
4     4     4    NA
5    NA    NA    NA
6     0     0     0

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(., na.rm = T) != 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1
2     0     0     1
3     4     4    NA
```

And if you cared about testing only certain columns (say a and b) you could use `select`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(select(., a, b), na.rm = T) != 0) 

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1
2     4     4    NA
```